# dispatchEvent alternative for IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, events, dom-events

Looking for a `dispatchEvent` alternative for iOS that allows me to emit an event.

`dispatchEvent()` is working fine for desktops and most of the devices.

But it is not seems to be working for iOS mobile devices.

Is there an alternative?

Below is my code:

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
          view: window,
          which: ENTER_KEY_CODE,
          keyCode: ENTER_KEY_CODE,
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
        });

document.querySelector('.free-text-search input').dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: It should work as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent#browser_compatibility

Comment: Maybe the underlying problem can be solved differently? Sounds like you're sending the enter key to a text field? Is this about submitting a form?

Comment: The question might be phrased wrong. `dispatchEvent()` works for iOS. The event you dispatch just might not have the result you expect that it should have. The same keyboard event can have different outcomes on different OS or browsers, especially if they trigger a certain UI/UX behavior. You, therefore, need to explain what you expect that should happen when that event is dispatched.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, you are right. I am trying to dispatch an 'Enter' event. This is on search bar.

Comment: @t.niese I can explain you the issue in detail. We have a search bar. we wanted to have a search icon on the right side of the search bar and on click of icon we wanted to target the search bar and dispatch an 'Enter' event so that we can see search results.

Comment: If you have a <form>, any <button> will submit it. Please post relevant HTML.

Comment: @ChrisG Search bar is coming from third party library.

Comment: Here is the entire code. we are using vue and search bar is a third party library.   ` methods: {
    dispatchSearchEvent(e) {
      if (e.target.matches('.magnifying-glass-icon')) {
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
          view: window,
          which: ENTER_KEY_CODE,
          keyCode: ENTER_KEY_CODE,
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
        });
        document.querySelector('.free-text-search-input').dispatchEvent(event);
      }
    },
  },`

Comment: Which library? What's the final HTML? Are you using a frontend framework?

Comment: @ChrisG Library name is Yotpo, We are using Yotpo widget. Yes it is a frontend library.

Comment: That library/service appears to provide several types of widgets. Please be specific, and include a link to what you are actually talking about here.